# Y AND X scrolling cards (ionic or angular way)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I would very much like to be able to do both vertical and horizontal scrolling with cards, like this:

[image]

Scrolling down would show fifth row with some cards. When doing vertical horizontal scrolling it would be awesome if the cards snaps into place when flipping through..

The `.json` would look like this:

```
{"first": ["1A"], 
"second": ["2A", "2B"], 
"third": ["3A", "3B"], 
"fourth": ["4A", "4B", "4C", "4D"],
"fifth": ["5A","5B"]}
```

Can this be done? Any pointers (like tutorials, libs or code examples) would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide any of your working on the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This **[Solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/u2XcPI?p=preview)** will work for you, it uses both **[ion-slides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/)**, and **[ion-scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/)** directives.

[image]

There is only one note to take care of;case you want to set initial page for each slider you will have to modify your JSON, and use the slider option `initialSlide`

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="starter">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
  <title>Card Scroller</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive"></ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Card Scroller">

      <ion-content class="padding" id="content">
        <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="y" class="scrolling-content">
          <ion-slides class="card" options="{pagination: false, initialSlide: 0, disableScroll:false}" slider="classA.slider" ng-repeat="slide in mySlides">

            <ion-slide-page class="page"  ng-repeat="item in slide">
            {{item}}
            </ion-slide-page>
          </ion-slides>

        </ion-scroll>
      </ion-content>

    </ion-view>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var nameApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);

nameApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

});


nameApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.mySlides = {
    "first": ["1A"],
    "second": ["2A", "2B"],
    "third": ["3A", "3B"],
    "fourth": ["4A", "4B", "4C", "4D"],
    "fifth": ["5A", "5B"]
  }

});
```

Comment: I seem to having to trouble scrolling through the cards. I need to grab it right between the cards to get a grip, but it snaps back after pulling..

Comment: @Norfeldt it is draggable, do you want only to swipe to scroll ? I dont get exact issue

Comment: Sorry for my newbie questions, but I'm just learning AngularJS and Ionic (and do struggle a bit with the CSS). Yes I wanted to use swipe to scroll because the gestures on mobile and web should be the same..

Comment: @Norfeldt well this swiper exactly imitates the native swipe UX for mobile, and because on web you are using mouse drag, you can control the delta though to make it more sensitive, anyway it works exact same on my touch ultrabook.

Comment: But why does the scroll snap back? I know it don't in your plunkr.. seems strange

Comment: @Norfeldt you can share your code, and I can help you with it :)

Comment: I really appreciate all your help. But due to the nature of AngularJS my code is so tangled up so it's hard to share without being one big mess.. I do miss Python... but like some of the super powers of AngularJS - like using ionic to build multi platform apps

Comment: @Norfeldt if you are using some source control, you may want to give me access, and I still would love to help.

Comment: I have used Git along the way (also a new thing I'm learning - going to web dev is a hard transition) but I'm not sure how I can share it..

Comment: @Norfeldt if it is publick just share repo link, else just add justgeek to repo

Comment: It isn't public, but I'll try to share it this weekend (it's an after work project). Hope you won't mind. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: @Norfeldt welcome anytime, it is my pleasure to help others :)